# Can't remotely connect to my postgresql database on digitalocean

Tags: postgresql, tcp, config, digital-ocean, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to my postgres db located on a digitalocean's droplet using  `psycopg2`  package.

However, I keep getting this error message :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "***.***.***.***", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I've made all the necessary modifications to both  `postgresql.conf` and  `pg_hba.conf` files, and restarted postgresql service.

```
#postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*' #both were uncommented 
port = 5432
```

```
#pg_hba.conf
host      all       all      0.0.0.0/0      md5
host      all       all      ::/0           md5
hostssl   all       all      0.0.0.0/0      md5   #tried with and without this line
```

When I run `service postgresql status` I see that my service is active.

And when I run  `netstat -na` I get the following :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

It looks like port 5432 is not open. I also tried using  `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp` but it didn't change anything.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

EDIT (to answer @Adrian Klaver's question) :

1. I run  `netstat -na` both in root and postgres.
2. `sudo ufw status` return the following :

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

3. `ps ax | grep postgres` returns the following :

```
 9320 pts/0    S+     0:00 sudo -u postgres psql
   9321 pts/1    Ss     0:00 sudo -u postgres psql
   9322 pts/1    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/psql
   9721 pts/2    S+     0:00 sudo -i -u postgres
   9722 pts/3    Ss     0:00 sudo -i -u postgres
  10141 pts/5    S+     0:00 sudo -i -u postgres
  10142 pts/6    Ss     0:00 sudo -i -u postgres
  10234 pts/7    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

4. there's no external firewall

Comment: Add answers to following as **text** update to question text. 1) Where did you run `netstat -na`. 2) What does `sudo ufw status` return? 3) What does `ps ax | grep postgres` show? 4) Is there an external firewall?

Comment: i edited my question with you inputs. thx :)

Comment: 1) I don't see any indication that the Postgres server is running. 2) What is the OS for the droplet?